# Deserializing a JSON object that contains a list of objects; returns Null for the nested object

Tags: c#, json, arraylist, json-deserialization

This is my first attempt of working with JSON deserialization. I have read many of the posts in Stackoverflow, non of the suggested solutions could match my issue, so my apology in advance. I have created the following objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LSum { get; set; }
    public int YSum { get; set; }
    public int TSum { get; set; }
    public int NSum { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
}

public class Something
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool ExistingMember { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Item { get; set; }
}
```

And when deserialize the JSON it looks like following:
The follwoing JSON what I expect it to be:

```
    {
   "Id":62,
   "Phone":"07",
   "ExistingMember":true,
   "Item":[
      {
         "ID":42,
         "LSum":0,
         "YSum":0,
         "TSum":0,
         "NSum":0,
         "MemberId":12
      }
   ]
}
```

However the following method it

```
   some= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<something>(someResponse);
```

It prints the json like the following:
The following JSON is what is "someResponse" return,

```
{
   "Id":62,
   "Phone":"07",
   "ExistingMember":true,
   "Item":null
}
```

What am I missing that the item list is return null?

Comment: Are you sure that `someResponse` has any item? I've tried your code and it works but only if `someResponse` has an item. So, double check it.

Comment: @DmitryStepanov Please check the jsons in the question. I just edit it

Comment: You see that the someResponse should deserializ "something"including the list of Items inside it. but for now it does not

Comment: As I can see you deserialize json string which is `someResponse` into c# object `some`. So, if `someResponse`doesn't contain any item, then `some` will have `Item` of `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deserialize json string which in your case is `someResponse` variable, then you are doing it right.

To check your code I created a JSON file with a **file.json** name and put the following on it:

```
{
  "Id": 62,
  "Phone": "07",
  "ExistingMember": true,
  "Item": [
    {
      "ID": 42,
      "LSum": 0,
      "YSum": 0,
      "TSum": 0,
      "NSum": 0,
      "MemberId": 12
    }
  ]
}
```

Then below lines of code take the content of JSON file (which in your case is the content of `someResponse`) and deserialize it into c# object of `Something` type:

```
string jsonFilePath = @"C:\test\file.json";

var some = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Something>(File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath));
```

Then print the `ID` property of each element of `Item` list:

```
foreach(var item in some.Item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"item ID = {item.ID}");
    }               
}
```

The output:

```
item ID = 42
```

So, it is quite possible that `someResponse` just does not have an `Item` and looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": 62,
  "Phone": "07",
  "ExistingMember": true
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also I tried like this:

```
var someResponse = @"{
  'Id': 62,
  'Phone': '07',
  'ExistingMember': true,
  'Item':[
    {
      'ID': 42,
      'LSum': 0,
      'YSum': 0,
      'TSum': 0,
      'NSum': 0,
      'MemberId': 12
    }
  ]
}
";

var some = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Something>(someResponse);
```

And `some` has a `Item` list with 1 element
[image]

Comment: But Item is a list within the "something" object and it should be deserialized along with "something". Basically what I'm saying is Something object contains list of Items and it needs to be deserialized there

Comment: I think you are making a muddle with the terms of `serialization` and `deserialization`. 
`Serialization` is when we convert c# object into `json`.  
`Deserialization` is when we convert `json` into c# object.
So, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to convert JSON into C# object that object contains list of "item". and for now the list of items is null even though the JSON contains a populated list of item

Comment: It's very odd. I don't know why you have this issue. Did you check `someResponse` in debug mode? You say that "you expect it to be". It's very strange. You should absolutely know what it is.

Comment: @dolly_do, No reproduction of your error https://rextester.com/AIJDS96750 . The code works.

Comment: After long time and struggle, I deleted everything and started over, copied what Dmitry has posted and it works.